# Creating security permissions for a non-domain-member user in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-management, cross-domain

I apologize in advance for incorrect use of terminology, as I'm not an IT person by trade.

I'm doing some remote work via a VPN for a client and I need to add some DCOM Service security permissions for my remote user. Even though I'm on the VPN, the request for access to the DCOM service is using my PCs native user (and since I'm running Vista Home Premium it looks something like: PC-NAME\Username). The request for access comes back with access denied and I can not add this user to the security permissions as it "is not from a domain listed in the Select Location dialog box, and is therefore not valid".

I'm pretty stuck and have no clue what kind of steps I need to do here. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have no control over what credentials are being passed in to the server by my computer. This scenario is occurring in an installation wizard that has a section which requests you point it to the machine running the "server" version of the software I'm installing (it then tries to invoke the relevant COM service, but my user does not have "Remove Activation Permissions" on that service, so I get request denied).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is assuming that you have an actual Domain account that you are able to authenticate with.  I'm not familiar with this exact issue, but on the program you are trying to open, you may be able to SHIFT + Right-Click and select Run As.  Then type your DOMAIN\Username as the username and your network password.  This should be the same as your VPN domain, username, and password.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The program I'm trying to run is actually an .msi installer (I also have a setup.exe file I could run, alternatively). The .msi doesn't give me a run-as option and the .exe only lets me "Run As Administrator". This might have to do with my OS being Vista Home Premium.

Comment: You should still be able to hold SHIFT and Right-Click to get the Run As... prompt.  Maybe not though on an .msi installer :)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether the server belongs to the domain or is operating standalone, it is going to attempt to authenticate a connection being made to it.  When a windows client connects to that server, it defaults to passing the credentials of user account that is currently logged into the client.  This will usually be Machine-Name\Username (standalone) or DomainName\Username (domain account) depending on which kind of account is logged on.

As long as the Server is not a domain controller, it can either utilize logins that are domain user accounts OR a local accounts present on that server.  Your choices then are as follows:

1. Create or use a domain user account with permissions on that server to perform the operations you require
2. Create a local user account on that server with the permissions set that will allow you to perform the operations you require

In both cases, you will have to pass the credentials to that server before the operation can be executed.  Those credentials will look like Domain\Username or Server\Username plus the password.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I should probably edit my question to make this clear: I have no control over what credentials are being passed in to the server by my computer. This is occurring in an installation wizard that has a part which requests you point it to the machine running the "server" version of the software.